# Debugging a deployed cloud service app

Tags: azure, rdlc, visual-studio-debugging, azureservicebus, intellitrace

How can a deployed cloud service application be debugged?

I am trying to render a RDLC report in my application using Topics & Subscriptions.
Whenever I run the cloud app locally, I don't receive any errors. But as soon as I deploy it over the cloud, I get an error which aren't described up to an extent so that it can be rectified.

I found that the error comes when the report is ready to be rendered and not anywhere else.
I am looking for a possible mechanisms (inserting breakpoints like we do locally, etc.) using which it is possible to debug a deployed cloud app.

Since I am using VS2012 Express & professional, intellitrace does not work here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable [Remote Debugging](http://www.4tecture.ch/blog/remote-debugging-a-windows-azure-role-instance) for your Role, and you will be able to debug your code in the cloud with any type of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, however Intellitrace was build for that purpose. You enable Intellitrace in your cloud instances, and then you can "playback" that instance locally, thus debugging and spotting the exceptions thrown.

Here's MSDN's article on that
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Having Intellitrace only in the most expensive version of Visual Studio makes developing for Azure far more expensive than it is advertised at. There are some situations, such as when a role is starting up, that you pretty much can't do anything without Intellitrace. If you find that you are in one of those edge cases 'evaluate' VS ultimate in a local virtual machine. You may need to re-evaluate at some point in the future, in which case you will need another VM.